# Null value comes from Post method (FromBody) when API is invoked from Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

Post method parameter is taken as null when API is invoked from Powershell.
Below is the JSON:

```
 "TestCase":{
    "tc_name":"TestCase1"
    },
    "3":{
    "scn_desc":"Create Client34345",
    "test_status":"PASS",
    "error_link":""
    }   ,
  "4":{
    "scn_desc":"Create Client43634",
    "test_status":"PASS",
    "error_link":""
    },
  "5":{
    "scn_desc":"Create Client346346",
    "test_status":"PASS",
    "error_link":""
    }   
  }
```

`$json` contains the above JSON array.
Powershell:
Invoke-WebRequest

-Uri http://localhost:65452/api/e10/e10PostTCData -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json'

API:

```
 [Route("e10PostTCData/")]
 [HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage PostResults([FromBody]JsonArray jsonArray )
 {

 }

 public class JsonArray
 {
   public string json { get; set; }
 }
```

Other way:

```
[Route("e10PostTCData/")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostResults([FromBody]String jsonArray )
{

}
```

Both the methods shows null as the parameter. Please advise.

Comment: Yes. But when passed to API the parameter comes as null in API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In form like this your service expects to receive json with `json` field on top level, same like your class `JsonArray.json` field. So in this case your request body should be something like:

```
{
    "json": "Whatever text you need to pass here"
}
```

If you want to pass your JSON body, you need to have a class that has all the same fields as your JSON has keys.

Otherwise you can read your JSON as string, convert to JSON and process manually, like:

```cs
   [Route("e10PostTCData")]
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<string> PostResults()
   {
       var bytes = new byte[(int)Request.ContentLength.Value];
       await Request.Body.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

       var content =  Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
       var json = JObject.Parse(content);

       return json["TestCase"]["tc_name"].ToString();
   }
```

For json body:

```
{
    "TestCase":{
        "tc_name":"TestCase1"
    },
    "3": {
        "scn_desc":"Create Client34345",
        "test_status":"PASS",
        "error_link":""
    }   ,
    "4":{
        "scn_desc":"Create Client43634",
        "test_status":"PASS",
        "error_link":""
    },
    "5":{
        "scn_desc":"Create Client346346",
        "test_status":"PASS",
        "error_link":""
    }   
}
```

Response

```
TestCase1
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to receive JSON as a string argument to your endpoint:

```cs
    public string PostResults([FromBody]string jsonStr)
    {
        // Use JObject class methods Parse or ToObject (deserialize) your string into object
        return jsonStr;
    }
```

Then your request should be a multiline string, NOT A JSON, which is very inconvenient unless you're the only user for your endpoint. For instance:

```
'{
    "TestCase":{
        "tc_name":"TestCase1"
    },
    "3": {
        "scn_desc":"Create Client34345",
        "test_status":"PASS",
        "error_link":""
    }   ,
    "4":{
        "scn_desc":"Create Client43634",
        "test_status":"PASS",
        "error_link":""
    },
    "5":{
        "scn_desc":"Create Client346346",
        "test_status":"PASS",
        "error_link":""
    }   
}'
```

**UPDATE:**
I amm not sure about all specifics of PowerShell, but the following worked for me:

```bsh
> $obj='{
      "TestCase":{
          "tc_name":"TestCase1"
      }
  }'
> Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:65452/api/e10/e10PostTCData -Body $(echo $obj | ConvertTo-Json) -Method POST -ConventType "application/json"
```

Comment: What about the other way. 
        [Route("e10PostTCData/")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostResults([FromBody]string jsonArray )
        {
        }
Passing the complete json as string in API body. Is there any way?

Comment: Below is the powershell script I am using to invoke the API:
$obj = "{""TestCase"":{"
$obj = $obj + "`n""tc_name"":TestCase1"""
$obj = $obj + "}"
$obj = $obj + "`n""}"

$obj

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:65452/api/e10/e10PostTCData -Method Post -Body $obj

But the parameter comes as null.

[Route("e10PostTCData/")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostResults([FromBody] string jsonArray )
        {

        }

Comment: @ShreyasMurali, check out my latest update, that should help.

Comment: Thank you! and below code should also work.                                            
Invoke-WebRequest-Uri http://localhost:65452/api/e10/e10PostTCData -Method Post -Body =$obj

Answer (score 0):

Powershell API request should be like below if the json data is sent in its body:

Invoke-WebRequest-Uri http://localhost:65452/api/e10/e10PostTCData -Method Post -Body =$json